# Differences in language identification langid

Tags: python

I have a database from which I read. I want to identify the language in a specific cell, defined by column. I am using the [langid](https://github.com/saffsd/langid.py) library for python.

I read from my database like this:

```
connector = sqlite3.connect("somedb.db")
selecter = connector.cursor()
selecter.execute(''' SELECT tags FROM sometable''')
for row in selecter: #iterate through all the rows in db
    #print (type(row)) #tuple
    rf = str(row)
    #print (type(rf)) #string
    lan = langid.classify("{}".format(rf))
```

Technically, it works. It identifies the languages used and later on (not displayed here) writes the identified language back into the database.

So, now comes the weird part. 
I wanted to double check some results manually. So I have these words:

```
a = "shadow party people bw music mer white man black france men art nature monochrome french fun shoe sand nikon europe noir noiretblanc sable playa poetic nb ombre shade contraste plage blanc saxophone dunkerque nord homme musique saxo artiste artistique musicien chaussure blancandwhite d90 saxophoniste zyudcoote"
```

When I perform the language identification on the `database` it plots me Portuguese into the database.
But, performing it like this:

```
a = "shadow party people bw music mer white man black france men art nature monochrome french fun shoe sand nikon europe noir noiretblanc sable playa poetic nb ombre shade contraste plage blanc saxophone dunkerque nord homme musique saxo artiste artistique musicien chaussure blancandwhite d90 saxophoniste zyudcoote"
lan = langid.classify(a)
```

Well, that returns me French. Apart from that it is neither French nor Portuguese, why is it returned different results?!

Answer (score 1):

In the loop `row` is bound to a *tuple* with a single item, i.e. `('tags',)` - where `'tags'` stands for the list of words. `str(row)` therefore (in Python 3) returns `"('tags',)"` and it is this string (including the single quotes, commas and braces) that is being passed to `langid.classify()`. If you are using Python 2 the string becomes `"(u'tags',)"`.

Now, I am not sure that this explains the different language detection result, and my testing in Python 2 shows that it doesn't, but it is an obvious difference between database sourced data and the plain string data.

Possibly there is some encoding issue coming into play. How is the data stored in the database? Text data should be UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: Hey, I am working in Python 3.3 and doing the `str(row)` does not return `(tags),`. I iterate over a database and I get different results for every row. If every row would be `(tags),`  then the language should be the same for every row. 
I think I am looking at coding issues as well. I create the field with `FIELD NAME, TEXT` which sets the the coding by default from SQLite to `UTF-8`. The data I recieve are screen scraped from the flickr API, but according to their Documentation `UTF-8` as well.

Comment: By `tags` I mean the contents of the tags field... Not the literal string `tags`. You are passing a stringified tuple to classify. I doubt that the problem is caused by that, but it is wrong to pass that as the string and you should fix that to eliminate it as being the problem.

Comment: Missunderstanding. I pass it that way now: `a = ''.join(row)`. Better?

Comment: Well, that works, but typically you would do it as `row[0]`. I wouldn't call `str()` on it either - that is likely to fail if you have non-ascii characters (which would be typical for non-english languages). Instead just do `lan = langid.classify(row[0])`

Comment: Okay. I thought python 3.x works with unicode and not ascii? 
`row[0]` wont work because there are empty rows hence empty tuples coming back. That raises an error

Comment: Sorry, you're on Python 3 so yes, unicode all the way. Get rid of empty rows by modifying the query to `SELECT tags FROM sometable WHERE tags IS NOT NULL`. If you don't like that, or In case there are also empty strings in the tags field, you can check for both with `if row[0]:`.